# utilize a single channel to transmit data generated from 16 users (using mux)

Tags: communication, multiplexer

I have found this question in a book and find it confusing. The question is,

For a communication system, it is required to utilize a single channel to transmit the data generated from 16 users. Design a feasible circuit to aggregate the 16 users to a single channel using 4:1 multiplexers. Design a user selection circuit to interface with the above designed aggregation circuit.
Please help me get an answer for this with explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the left, I've used `2:1` muxes and then boxed them together to create a bigger `4:1` mux. Using this construction method of building larger muxes from smaller muxes you can construct your `16:1` mux. As shown in the schematic, the dashed boxes represent a `4:1` mux, so only 5 `4:1` muxes are necessary to construct your `16:1` mux; 4 on the bottom layer and one for the top layer. The key insight is to build them using a tree structure. Also, each `4:1` mux requires two select bits, one bit for each layer of the mux tree. I will leave it to you to design the larger `16:1` mux select circuit. Hint: each layer requires two bits! For example lets say we want to select user #10 (with user #0 at the top): our select line would be a 4-bit bus with value `0101`.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9WaJu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. You mean for the selection circuit I can use the 8 selectors in the first four muxes? so I can use them to select the user?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example to select user #10. So there would be a two-bit bus going to the first layer of `4:1` muxes then another 2-bit bus going to the second `4:1` mux layer. Only two selectors, each 2-bits.